# Architecture Advice: Grails and Video Content

Tags: java, video, upload

I'm looking at a new (big) project.  The project involves a lot of user-uploaded video content.

I'm leaning towards building this in Grails, I've done a ton of Java in the past.

Currently, my thought for handling the storage of the videos is to write the file to a mount, and then save the location in the DB.

Is there some other options I should consider?  I am wondering if something like JackRabbit (or Hadoop, but this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044050/image-processing-with-hadoop) seems to suggest not) might be something I should look further into.

I'm concerned about scalability going forward, and trying to keep things simple when deployed into a cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a similar thing 2 years ago and we have put the video in a separate media server using FTP. We stored server name and file location in the database like you have said. This way we could upload thousands of videos and use clusters without any problems.

The media server was tuned to serve static files using apache. This way videos are not served via tomcat or your servlet container.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Houcem.